# Image changes when blurred

Tags: image-processing

Consider the following image. [image: original image]

As you know, WhatsApp shows blurred thumbnails of images in chats until they are downloaded. In this case, when I send the image to others by WhatsApp, the blurred thumbnail looks something like this: [image: blurred thumbnail]

(To reproduce the effect, try sending the original image to a friend and delete the original from **Internal Storage/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Images**.)

The original and blurred images look completely different. How is this effect achieved?

I have noticed that the original image contains a grid of dots superimposed on it. Is the blurred image formed by those dots? Also, is it possible to merge any two images in this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The superimposed image is not blurred. That's another step. But you are right. The second image is in the grid. The abuse the fact that Whatsapp subsamples the image to create a preview.

Comment: Could you please explain this subsampling process?

Comment: @KaranKaran just google image subsampling... to make an image smaller you can copy an image by only taking every nth pixel. In this case every 4th pixel in x and y contains the superimposed image.